# ASP.NET, ScriptManager, History Points and Dynamic Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET user control that I want to write some dynamic Javascript to (basically a JQuery call to open an accordion node).

To complicate matters, I'm using history points. In a nutshell, I need to open a JQueryUI accordion based on a value in the history point data stored in the URL.

I've got the part that sets the history points working, and I can step through my code (below) as I navigate the history. The problem is, in this example, my script never renders on the page.

```
protected void uxScriptManager_OnNavigate(Object sender, HistoryEventArgs e)
    { 
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.State["activeTab"]))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "xScript", "alert('Hello,world!');", true);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Addendum**

I've been tinkering, and it seems like my call to register the clientscriptblock works fine in other events...but in the Navigate event for the scriptmanager, I can't write new script out to the page. I'm thinking what I'm trying to do isn't possible...

Comment: Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278466/html-elements-hiding-after-asp-button-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add script by calling [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method to show elements on page:

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), this.ID,
>   ""alert('Hello,world!');", true);

Comment: Hi Ivan.  I tried that - but what seems to be happening is on the Navigate event, I can't add new script blocks to the page. I think it's because the page is being read out of history, not being fully re-rendered. Server-side calls are working fine, but in this particular case I need to hook in a client side script, and it doesn't look like it's possible. (If I move that same block of code for the script to another event, it works fine)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, it doesn't look like it's possible to write new client script out to a page - or change values in an existing script block - on the Navigate event. I'm noting this in case anyone else tries to do the same thing.

**CORRECTION**

I found out it *is* possible to do what I want!

- I need to set the history point in an early part of the page lifecycle
- I need to set the dynamic script in the RegisterStartupScript method for **the page**

(Ivan's post pointed me in the right direction, so I've flagged his post as the answer)